# How to use .swift files in app bundle?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

How to add file like "`SomeCodeFile.swift`" so that I can copy it from Bundle ?

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SomeCodeFile", withExtension: "swift")!
```

If I add files to `Copy Bundle Resources` items, I can't run project, because it trying to build these files too. However, I don't have them in `Compile Source` section. Any help?

Comment: add it compressed in zip and then open and send or what you want to do

Comment: It is just a text file so all you need is to change its extension from `.swift` to `.txt`